# Can't send raw data into command (bash)

Tags: bash, macos, base64, 7zip, ogg

I want to store an .ogg file inside of a bash script and play it later on in the script. I have tried:

- Archiving the .ogg into a .7z file (saves some space), encoding the .7z archive into base64, storing that base64 into my script, and decoding->unzipping->playing the raw .ogg stream.
- Encoding the .ogg into base64, storing that base64 into my script, and decoding->playing the raw ogg stream.
- Creating a hex dump of the .ogg file, storing that hex into my script, using sed to place `\x` before every two characters of the hex, using printf to print the hex and `<<<` it into `ogg123` (my ogg player)
- Archiving the .ogg into a .7z file (saves some space), creating a hex dump of the .7z file, storing that hex into my script, using sed to place `\x` before every two characters of the hex, using printf to print the hex, pipe the output into `7za e -si` and `<<<` it into `ogg123` (my ogg player)

None of these work. The most successful approach I have had is:

```
ogg123 <<< cat sound.ogg
```

However I would really prefer to have no files written to the disk (want to keep it all stored in my script) and, if possible, not use variable(s) to store any of the raw data.

Another problem is, `ogg123` does not support reading from stdin, therefore I can't pipe the any raw ogg data into it.

Commands I have tried: (hex and base64 are truncated of course)

```
$ ogg123 <<< printf 'xae\x0f\x00\xad\x83' # .ogg data
/usr/local/bin/ogg123: Argument list too long

$ ogg123 <(printf 'xae\x0f\x00\xad\x83') # .ogg data
Error opening /dev/fd/63 using the oggvorbis module.  The file may be corrupted.

$ S=<<SOUND
dGhpcyBiYXNlNjQgd291bGQgYmUgdGhlIGJhc2U2NCBvZiBteSBvZ2cgZmlsZQ==
SOUND
$ ogg123 <(echo $S | openssl base64 -d)
Error opening /dev/fd/63 using the oggvorbis module.  The file may be corrupted.
$ ogg123 <<< echo $S | openssl base64 -d
5?w?k譸?
```

I did try several other commands, however I accidentally quit Terminal and those two were the only commands saved in my .bash_history. But believe me, though, everything I tried got me nowhere (I've spent 3.5 hours on this already with no success).

Using macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, bash 3.2.57(1)-release, ogg123 from vorbis-tools 1.4.0, 7za 16.02 (x64), `openssl base64` (LibreSSL 2.2.7).

Comment: `ogg123 <<< cat sound.ogg` doesn't do what you think it does. Ex. compare `ogg123 sound.ogg <<< cat `

Comment: Ahh, yep those both did the same :-/

Comment: The `<<< cat` redirects the string "cat" to command standard input. It then runs `ogg123` with `sound.ogg` as the argument. Same with `ogg123 <<< echo $S`. It redirects the string "echo" to command `ogg123 $S`. Also, always quote your variables. Sadly, if `ogg123` can't open a stream, you will have to create a `tmpfile` just for it. Could you try `ogg123 /dev/stdin <sound.ogg`? What if you used a fifo `mkfifo /tmp/somefile.ogg; ( cat sound.ogg > /tmp/somefifo.ogg; ); off123 /tmp/somefifo.ogg`? Maybe it needs the extension of the file to be `.ogg`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yep, tried both of those and they worked. And doing `ogg123 sound` worked (doesn't care if .ogg isn't present in the name.)

Comment: This doesn't really _fix_ the problem, per se, but I found that using `mplayer` instead worked much better (`mplayer <(printf '\x01\xca\x23')`) Haven't fully messed around with base64 or 7z yet, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete fix, but I did get it to work with the following:

```
mplayer <(openssl base64 -d <<SND
dGhpcyBiYXNlNjQgd291bGQgYmUgdGhlIGJhc2U2NCBvZiBteSBvZ2cgZmlsZQ==
SND
)
```

Props to `mplayer` for reading raw data like that (also worked reading from stdin!)